# How to fix invalid argument error in tensorflow LSTM

Tags: tensorflow, lstm

I am trying an LSTM encoder-decoder network and get an invalid argument error. I have just started working with so I don't have much experience.

```
    # split a multivariate sequence into samples
def split_sequences(sequences, n_steps_in, n_steps_out):
    X, y = list(), list()
    for i in range(len(sequences)):
        # find the end of this pattern
        end_ix = i + n_steps_in
        out_end_ix = end_ix + n_steps_out-1
        # check if we are beyond the dataset
        if out_end_ix > len(sequences):
            break
        # gather input and output parts of the pattern
        seq_x, seq_y = sequences[i:end_ix, :-1], sequences[end_ix-1:out_end_ix, -1]
        X.append(seq_x)
        y.append(seq_y)
    return np.array(X), np.array(y)
    #Devide Train and Test Set
train_X,train_y = split_sequences(train ,24,12)
test_X , test_y = split_sequences(test, 24, 12)
print(train_X.shape)
print(train_y.shape)
print(test_X)

    # design network
model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(100, activation='tanh', input_shape=(n_timesteps, n_features)))
model.add(RepeatVector(n_outputs))
model.add(LSTM(100, activation='tanh',return_sequences=True))
model.add(TimeDistributed(Dense (100 ,activation = 'tanh')))
model.add(TimeDistributed(Dense(12)))
model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='mse',metrics = ['mape', 'mae', 'mse'])
plot_model(model=model, show_shapes=True)
# fit network
history = model.fit(train_X, train_y, epochs=70, batch_size=16, validation_data=(test_X, test_y), verbose=0, shuffle=False)
# plot history
plt.plot(history.history['loss'], label='train')
plt.plot(history.history['val_loss'], label='test')
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

And I keep getting this error which I have no idea what to do about.

```
 54     tensors = pywrap_tfe.TFE_Py_Execute(ctx._handle, device_name, op_name,
---> 55                                         inputs, attrs, num_outputs)
     56   except core._NotOkStatusException as e:
     57     if name is not None:

InvalidArgumentError: Graph execution error:

Detected at node 'sub_1' defined at (most recent call last):
    File "/usr/lib/python3.7/runpy.py", line 193, in _run_module_as_main
      "__main__", mod_spec)
    File "/usr/lib/python3.7/runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
      exec(code, run_globals)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/ipykernel_launcher.py", line 16, in <module>
      app.launch_new_instance()
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/traitlets/config/application.py", line 846, in launch_instance
      app.start()
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/ipykernel/kernelapp.py", line 499, in start
      self.io_loop.start()
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tornado/platform/asyncio.py", line 132, in start
      self.asyncio_loop.run_forever()
    File "/usr/lib/python3.7/asyncio/base_events.py", line 541, in run_forever
      self._run_once()
    File "/usr/lib/python3.7/asyncio/base_events.py", line 1786, in _run_once
      handle._run()
    File "/usr/lib/python3.7/asyncio/events.py", line 88, in _run
      self._context.run(self._callback, *self._args)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tornado/platform/asyncio.py", line 122, in _handle_events
      handler_func(fileobj, events)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tornado/stack_context.py", line 300, in null_wrapper
      return fn(*args, **kwargs)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/zmq/eventloop/zmqstream.py", line 452, in _handle_events
      self._handle_recv()
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/zmq/eventloop/zmqstream.py", line 481, in _handle_recv
      self._run_callback(callback, msg)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/zmq/eventloop/zmqstream.py", line 431, in _run_callback
      callback(*args, **kwargs)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tornado/stack_context.py", line 300, in null_wrapper
      return fn(*args, **kwargs)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/ipykernel/kernelbase.py", line 283, in dispatcher
      return self.dispatch_shell(stream, msg)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/ipykernel/kernelbase.py", line 233, in dispatch_shell
      handler(stream, idents, msg)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/ipykernel/kernelbase.py", line 399, in execute_request
      user_expressions, allow_stdin)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/ipykernel/ipkernel.py", line 208, in do_execute
      res = shell.run_cell(code, store_history=store_history, silent=silent)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/ipykernel/zmqshell.py", line 537, in run_cell
      return super(ZMQInteractiveShell, self).run_cell(*args, **kwargs)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py", line 2718, in run_cell
      interactivity=interactivity, compiler=compiler, result=result)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py", line 2822, in run_ast_nodes
      if self.run_code(code, result):
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py", line 2882, in run_code
      exec(code_obj, self.user_global_ns, self.user_ns)
    File "<ipython-input-104-5b6253fe4137>", line 2, in <module>
      history = model.fit(train_X, train_y, epochs=70, batch_size=16, validation_data=(test_X, test_y), verbose=0, shuffle=False)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/utils/traceback_utils.py", line 64, in error_handler
      return fn(*args, **kwargs)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1384, in fit
      tmp_logs = self.train_function(iterator)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1021, in train_function
      return step_function(self, iterator)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1010, in step_function
      outputs = model.distribute_strategy.run(run_step, args=(data,))
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1000, in run_step
      outputs = model.train_step(data)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 864, in train_step
      return self.compute_metrics(x, y, y_pred, sample_weight)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 957, in compute_metrics
      self.compiled_metrics.update_state(y, y_pred, sample_weight)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/engine/compile_utils.py", line 459, in update_state
      metric_obj.update_state(y_t, y_p, sample_weight=mask)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/utils/metrics_utils.py", line 70, in decorated
      update_op = update_state_fn(*args, **kwargs)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/metrics.py", line 178, in update_state_fn
      return ag_update_state(*args, **kwargs)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/metrics.py", line 729, in update_state
      matches = ag_fn(y_true, y_pred, **self._fn_kwargs)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/losses.py", line 1457, in mean_absolute_error
      return backend.mean(tf.abs(y_pred - y_true), axis=-1) Node: 'sub_1' required broadcastable shapes      [[{{node sub_1}}]] [Op:__inference_train_function_764649]
```

Comment: Why have you used the `RepeatVector` layer? I guess the error is due to this layer.

Comment: No, not actually. So any idea?

Comment: The last line of the error log would have been beneficial to find the exact answer as you know Python has very descriptive logs which can help us trace the error. However this error which you have mentioned typically occurs when the shape of the input to the Flatten layer is not what the layer expects. For instance, if you provide a 3D input to a Flatten layer expecting a 2D input, you will encounter this error. To resolve it, Check the input shape `print(input_data.shape)` . If it does not match the flatten layer, reshape as per its shape. Check the model summary then . It will help avoid it.